# Dynamically created controls names not increasing its value through loops C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a personal project where I'm building a notes generator, and I have this TextBox dynamically created everytimes a button is clicked, it works fine just like how I expected but things gets weird when I tried to name each of these TextBox to different name by using a loop `Name = "Note" + i` where `i` is the loop variable.

So what I was expecting to happens is that each of the TextBox names to be something like `Note1` `Note2` `Note3 ...`  but instead when I retrieved each of the TextBox name to a MessageBox in the same loop which is used to generates the TextBox, the MessageBox throws this: `Note 1` `Note 1` `Note 1 ...` instead when I clicked the button thrice.

```
int curr = 0;
private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int top = 25;
    int h_p = 170;
    curr++;
    for(int i=1; i<curr+1; i++) {
        // Notes
        var new_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
            Text = "Title\n",
            Name = "Note" + i,
            Multiline = true,
            AcceptsTab = true,
            AcceptsReturn = true,
            WordWrap = false,
            ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical,
            Width = 220,
            Height = 110,
            BorderRadius = 8,
            Font = new Font("Bahnschrift", 13),
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            FillColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1E1E1E"),
            BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2C2C"),
            Location = new Point(450,top)
        };

        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

        top += h_p;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new_note);
        curr = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting _curr_ back to 0 before exiting the event handler. At the next call you get again 1

Comment: One more thought to that what @Steve wrote: you are setting `curr` to 0 in each loop

Comment: Still I don't understand why you have for...loop here. You say that you want to create a single TextBox each time the button is clicked, so there is no need of a loop. And if you need to know the next indexer then a better approach instead of using a global variable is to use the Count property of the FlowLayoutPanel.Controls collection. (If there are only textboxes there you just need to set _Name = "Note" + flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count + 1;_)

Comment: Be careful using the `Count` property if there is an ability to delete the controls in a random order. Then you could possibly end up with a duplicated name. A global variable that gets incremented is probably the safest bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use the `For` loop in this case. You can just use the variable `curr` for each textboxes. So instead of the `For` loop, you can use this :

```
int top = 25;
int h_p = 170;
curr++;
var new_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
    Text = "Title\n",
    Name = "Note" + curr,
    Multiline = true,
    AcceptsTab = true,
    AcceptsReturn = true,
    WordWrap = false,
    ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical,
    Width = 220,
    Height = 110,
    BorderRadius = 8,
    Font = new Font("Bahnschrift", 13),
    ForeColor = Color.White,
    FillColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1E1E1E"),
    BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2C2C"),
    Location = new Point(450,top)
    
    top += h_p;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new_note);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that inside the loop you set always curr back to zero. And the loop is not needed at all because you want to add a textbox at each click. So you just need to look at the Count property of the FlowLayoutPanel and use that value to prepare the name.
Another problem to solve is how to position the next control inside the panel but again you could calculate easily with a the Count property

```
private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int nextTop = 25 + (flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count * 170);
    var new_note = new Guna2TextBox() {
        Text = "Title\n",
        Name = "Note" + flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count + 1,
        .....
        Location = new Point(450,nextTop)
    };
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new_note);
}
```